# Get Event Subscriptions with Reflection

Tags: c#

I'm trying to loop through all event subscriptions for an object that `: INotifyPropertyChanged`  This is as far as I can get:

```
EventInfo e1 = typeof(INotifyPropertyChanged).GetEvent("PropertyChanged",
   BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Now how would I go about getting all subscriptions to that event for a given `INotifyPropertyChanged` object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any simple way to create a generic solution for this since you have no way of knowing what the backing store for any given event might be.  While attempting to infer the backing store is possible, it's not exactly a robust or low-cost solution.  If you could share your end goal, it might be possible to suggest a more easily managed approach.

Comment: Well my end goal was to be able to loop through the current events, and remove the appropriate one. The way I had it originally I was adding event handlers that were anonymous methods, but I guess it's obvious now that I'm going to need something a little more robust, so I can say O.PropertyChanged += Foo; and then later O.PropertyChanged -= Foo; Thanks for your answer.